# Dual swappable multi-select boxes with search in Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-material-5

I'm trying to find some sort of two-sides multiple(always opened) boxes with search and angular material design but I can't find anything. 
I can achieve the same functionality, but the multiple dropdown select box gets always folded when I do backdrop click.

Should I write it on pure angular or find a way to do this with Angular Material?

Here is a link which almost fully represents functionality I want to achieve but without search and angular material:
https://alexklibisz.github.io/angular-dual-multiselect-directive/

Comment: The mutliselect dual list is an old UI pattern that isn't really necessary. Compared to material design UI patterns it is clumsy. Imagine how that control might work on a phone. Try a selection list with a filter field instead.

Comment: @G.Tranter Thanx for your reply, but the requirements say that this panel will only be used in a desktop version. And they designed it as a dual multi-select list. 
I saw your suggestion and yeah, its really the best way to do so.
I'll try to request a change in design and if so - that will be great.
Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: Okay. In my experience, the only use for such a control is when you need to reorder items. Without a reordering feature, the multi-list control is nothing more than an overly complex select/checkbox list. Also, drag-and-drop has replaced the need for reordering controls on lists.

Comment: @G.Tranter Thanx for the reply!